# HILT : lateinit property repository has not been initialized in ViewModel

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I am facing this issue in multi module android project with HILT.

```
 kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property repository has not been initialized in MyViewModel
```

My modules are

1. App Module
2. Viewmodel module
3. UseCase Module
4. DataSource Module

**'App Module'**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false)
}
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.test()
}}
```

**'ViewModel Module'**

```
class MainViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(private val repository: MyUsecase): ViewModel() {
fun test(){
    repository.test()
}}
```

**'UseCase Module'**

```
class MyUsecase @Inject constructor() {

@Inject
lateinit var feature: Feature

fun doThing() {
    feature.doThing()
}

@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object FeatureModule {
    @Provides
    fun feature(realFeature: RealFeature): Feature = realFeature
}
}
```

**'DataSource Module'**

```
interface Feature {
fun doThing()
}

class RealFeature : Feature {
override fun doThing() {
    Log.v("Feature", "Doing the thing!")
}
}
```

Dependencies are

MyFragment ---> MyViewModel ---> MyUseCase ---> DataSource

what i did wrong with this code pls correct it.

Comment: Have you tried using constructor injection in combination with `@ViewModelInject`?

Comment: More specifically, should just put the repository variable in your constructor. I'm guessing @ViewModelInject only supports constructor injection.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce ya tried. It's not working.   "Sometimes a type cannot be constructor-injected. This can happen for multiple reasons. For example, you cannot constructor-inject an interface. You also cannot constructor-inject a type that you do not own, such as a class from an external library. In these cases, you can provide Hilt with binding information by using Hilt modules."   This only document says

Comment: Sounds like `MyUsecase` is missing `@Inject constructor`

Comment: You can't constructor inject an interface, because an interface can't be constructed anyways. In this case, you own the actual implementation, which can be constructor injected. Yes, there are cases where field injection is the only answer, but at the moment your example doesn't need it, and you should move to constructor injection.

Answer (score 15):

above your activity class you must add annotation  @AndroidEntryPoint
as below:

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

Comment: Thanks. This little mistake take more then 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to moving all your stuff to constructor injection, your `RealFeature` isn't being injected, because you instantiate it manually rather than letting Dagger construct it for you. Note how your FeatureModule directly calls the constructor for RealFeature and returns it for the `@Provides` method. Dagger will use this object as is, since it thinks you've done all the setup for it. Field injection only works if you let Dagger construct it.

Your FeatureModule should look like this:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object FeatureModule {
    @Provides
    fun feature(realFeature: RealFeature): Feature = realFeature
}
```

Or with the `@Binds` annotation:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
interface FeatureModule {
    @Binds
    fun feature(realFeature: RealFeature): Feature
}
```

This also highlights why you should move to constructor injection; with constructor injection, this mistake wouldn't have been possible.

Comment: Updated my code.  Now 'not able to access RealFeature class'.  If i am using api instead of implementation then its work fine. @manuelvicnt says HILT support only api for multi module.

Comment: @Arun there's not enough here to diagnose a gradle issue. I'd need to see the whole project for that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the code is that `@ViewModelInject` doesn't work as `@Inject` in other classes. You cannot perform field injection in a ViewModel.

You should do:

```
class MainViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
  private val myUseCase: MyUsecase
): ViewModel() {

  fun test(){
    myUseCase.test()
  }
}
```

Consider following the same pattern for the `MyUsecase` class. Dependencies should be passed in in the constructor instead of being `@Inject`ed in the class body. This kind of defeats the purpose of dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now having another problem. Based on my example I can't able to inject "Feature" interface in "MyUsecase" class. it's says feature class cannot access.

Comment: At this point you kinda need to just upload something to github, since this is a gradle problem, not a dagger problem, and outside the scope of the original question.

Comment: `@ViewModelInject` is deprecated. Use `@HiltViewModel` instead. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66185820/14230540

Answer (score 0):

First, i think you are missing `@Inject` on your RealFeature class, so the Hilt knows how the inject the dependency. Second, if you want to inject into a class that is not a part of Hilt supported Entry points, you need to define your own entry point for that class.

In addition to the module that you wrote with `@Provides` method, you need to tell Hilt how the dependency can be accessed.

In your case you should try something like this:

```
@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
interface FeatureInterface {
    fun getFeatureClass(): Feature
}
```

Then, when you want to use it,  write something like this:

```
        val featureInterface =
        EntryPoints.get(appContext, FeatureInterface::class.java)
        val realFeature = featureInterface.getFeatureClass()
```

You can find more info here:

https://dagger.dev/hilt/entry-points

https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#not-supported

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(private val repository: HomePageRepository,
                                                 @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle)
: ViewModel(){}
```

and intead of initializing the viewmodel like this :
private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

Use this directly :

private val mainViewModel:MainViewModel by activityViewModels()

EXplanation :
**assisted saved state handle** : will make sure that if activity / fragment is annotated with @Android entry point combined with view model inject , it will automatically inject all required constructor dependencies available from corresonding component activity / application so that we won't have to  pass these parameters while initializing viewmodel in fragment / activity

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added class path and plugin

```
classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.35'
```

in Project.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
```

in app.gradle