# Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel using dagger hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, use-case, dagger-hilt

My ViewModel:

```
class LoginViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val loginUseCase: LoginUseCase
) : ViewModel() {

    val currentResult: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<String>()
    }

    fun loginUseCase(username: String, password: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            loginUseCase.invoke(username, password).apiKey.let {
                currentResult.value = it
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Is being used by my MainActivity:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val loginViewModel: LoginViewModel by viewModels()
```

And I know that the ViewModelProvider is expecting a empty constructor but I need to use the LoginUseCase:

```
class LoginUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val apiService: ApiServiceImpl
) : UseCase<Unit>() {
    suspend operator fun invoke(username: String, password: String) =
        apiService.login(username, password)
}
```

Inside the modelView, but i get the error:

Cannot create an instance of class com.example.myboards.ui.login.LoginViewModel

in runtime, and I dont know how I could manage the LoginUseCase inside the LoginViewModel

Comment: I am guessing this has got to do with the dependency in the app `build.gradle` file. Please share the `build.gradle` dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a `ViewModel` by annotating it with `@HiltViewModel` and using the `@Inject` annotation in the `ViewModel` object's constructor.

```
@HiltViewModel
class LoginViewModel @Inject constructor(
  private val loginUseCase: LoginUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
  ...
}
```

Hilt needs to know how to provide instances of ApiServiceImpl, too. Read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#inject-interfaces) to know how to inject interface instances with `@Binds`.

Let me know If you still have a problem.

Comment: Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66185820/1169441)